# chrome extension messes up my encoding

Tags: jquery, encoding, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that, when some event occurs, inserts a textarea into the current page. The page is encoded with `ISO-8859-15`. The User can then fill this textarea and after hitting some button, it's content is posted to the server via jquery's `$.post()`.

```
var textarea = $('<textarea id="pstmsg"></textarea>');
somediv.append(textarea);
...
$.post('url', {'text': textarea.val()}, function() {
        ...
});
```

There is another page, also `ISO-8859-15` encoded, where a static textarea within a form is in the html. Submitting that one works fine, but when I use my javascript methor above, the server messes up the special characters in the code, like `üäö` for example. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "the server messes up the special characters in the code"?

Comment: Well, the server writes that content into some database. Unfortunately, I have no access to that server, I am basically just imitating some html form with javascript. When I request the same content again from the server, the special characters are replaced by some cryptic characters, the typical wrong-encoding stuff.